# JPackage for only one application?

Tags: java, executable-jar, jpackage

I have a java application that at runtime shall spawn another JVM. Yet I want to package my application using jpackage, which works quite well. But at runtime, when my application tries to invoke the next JVM using

```
File javaHome = new File(System.getProperty("java.home"));
File java = new File(javaHome, "bin/java"); // may need a tweak on Windows
new ProcessBuilder().start(java.getAbsolutePath(), "-jar", ...);
```

I have to learn that the application was launched using a custom built JVM, and there just is no command such as 'java'. So the error I am getting is that this java.getAbsolutePath() cannot be executed.

Without the java executable, how can my application run another jar in a separate process? Can I reuse the JVM bundled with my application, or do I still have to provide another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `jpackage` will pass the following flags when invoking `jlink` to create the runtime image:

```
--strip-native-commands --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files
```

It is this `--strip-native-commands` flag that removes the `java` launcher from the runtime image.

You can use the `--jlink-options` flag when invoking `jpackage` to override the default commands, and drop the `--strip-native-commands` flag:

```
--jlink-options "--strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files"
```

That should result in the `java` command (as well as others) being present in the created runtime image.

---

If you want even more control over the custom JVM/runtime image used by jpackage, you could also manually run `jlink` to create a runtime image, and then pass that image to `jpackage` using the `--runtime-image` flag.